# Question about a vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling to find a counter-example for this question.

**QUESTION:**

Is $\nu$ a vector norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

We define the function $\nu: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$\nu(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n (|\text{Re }x_i|+|\text{Im }x_i|).$$

**ANSWER**

I know that is not a vector norm since $\nu(\alpha x) \ne |\alpha| \nu (x)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, that is $$|\alpha|\sum_{i=1}^n (|\text{Re }x_i|+|\text{Im }x_i|) \ne \sum_{i=1}^n (| \alpha \text{Re }x_i|+| \alpha \text{Im }x_i|)$$

Comment: And how do you know that the inequality in your answer is true? (Consider the case $n=1$)

Comment: My advice: keep it simple. First, choose a very low value of $n$. If $n = 1$ doesn't work (which it will), then try $n = 2$. The question only looks plausible because we tend to think too "real" when it comes to scalar multiplication, so try some non-real numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been thinking about this and I have found the answer to my question, we just need to think about the following:
$$(1-i)(1+i)=2$$

What I mean is that I have found a counter-example with $x=1+i$ and $\alpha=1-i$.